# VMPK: Use common slider control instead of dial control?

Tags: software, virtual-instrument

It uses a small dial control (Windows term. Maybe "widget" in Linux/Android term.) for changing the values. Maybe this is for someone who uses a real hardware dial and the dial reflects the hardware value? I don't know. But I am using mouse to change the values, so it is very awkward to use it. Is there a way to replace the dial control with something more sensible, like a slider or the numeric up-and-down as other parts of the window are using in the screenshot below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In menu `Edit` you will find `Shortcuts` which you can define by yourself. The default shortcut for changing the controller value seem to be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. Note, for <kbd>+</kbd> you either need to also hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> or use the numeric pad.